# Setting up OpenGL NetBeans project with GLFW on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, netbeans

I am trying to setup OpenGL developing environment on Ubuntu.I installed all the libs including GLFW as I don't want to use GLUT.GLEW lib has been installed too.I am trying to set it all in NetBeans.I have never used it before and currently I am getting :

**undefined reference to `glfwInit'**  error while running this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include "glm.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace glm;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


 /*      init GLFW         */
    if(!glfwInit()){

        fprintf(stderr,"failed to init GLFW");

     }
    return 0;
}
```

I am sure it is linker related problem.So I have added libglfw.a to Linker->Libraries and then got even more errors like these:

make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sasmaster/NetBeansProjects/OpenGLDemo'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86  g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/opengldemo build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o /usr/lib/libglfw.a 
/usr/lib/libglfw.a(window.o): In function`glfwOpenWindow':
/usr/lib/libglfw.a(x11_init.o): In function `_glfwPlatformInit':
/usr/lib/libglfw.a(x11_init.o): In function`_glfwPlatformInit':
/usr/lib/libglfw.a(x11_init.o): In function `_glfwPlatformInit':
/usr/lib/libglfw.a(x11_init.o): In function`_glfwPlatformInit':
/usr/lib/libglfw.a(x11_init.o): In function `_glfwPlatformTerminate':
/usr/lib/libglfw.a(x11_init.o): In function`_glfwPlatformTerminate':
/usr/lib/libglfw.a(x11_window.o): In function `translateKey':
/usr/lib/libglfw.a(x11_window.o): In function`translateKey':
/usr/lib/libglfw.a(x11_window.o): In function `translateKey':
/usr/lib/libglfw.a(x11_window.o): In function`translateChar':
...........
........................

What else should I link or install?

**Update:**
[Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dark-oberon/forums/forum/227592/topic/1337724) it is said one should add LIBRARIES='-pthread -lglfw -lGL -lX11 -lGLU -lXxf86vm'
But where should I add those in NetBeans properties? I tried put into the MakeFile and "linker options" too and nothing helped.

**Update1**
Compiling the main.cpp manually using this command:

```
**g++ main.cpp  -o Game -lglfw -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lpthread -lXxf86vm -lm**
```

Compiles fine.How do I link all these libs via NetBeans???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the solution.For those interested:
Openg Project properties.Then **"Linker"** ->**"Libraries"**.
In the Libraries dialog:
Click **"Add Option"** -> **"Other Option"**.
In the textfield insert these params:

**-lGLEW -lglfw -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lpthread -lXxf86vm -lm**

I guess lGLU is needed only if you use the old OpenGL version.

Comment: You are my freaggin hero. I love love love love you.

Comment: I was just beginning glfw as well. In my case, -lglfw -lGL is enough.

Comment: works  in netbeans 13 as well .  as pram said : -Lglfw -LGl is enough