# how do i get rid of these compiler errors in glu.h?

Tags: c++, opengl, netbeans, cygwin, glu

trying to use this [tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/) on 64-bit windows 8 with netbeans and cygwin 4.8.1.

i get many errors like this: /usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token.

on statements like this: void APIENTRY gluQuadricCallback(GLUquadric *qobj,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());

the pointer on error message points to the * before the fn().

edit: including windef.h gets rid of the compiler error messages.

i am left with a bunch of undefined references like: glfwInit

edit2: using André Fischer's ideas, i can get a clean compile (you need to add the directory and a -l option for the linker).

i now have a: skipping incompatible ../../../../../Windows/SysWOW64/opengl32.dll when searching for -lopengl32 and: undefined reference to `_*imp*_vsnprintf'. so it looks like i have a 32/64 bit problems and an undefined external.

there must be a saner way to get opengl working on windows.

Comment: Which bit of the tutorial? What does that line of glu.h say?

Comment: the first tutorial (tutorial01_first_window). the line says: void APIENTRY gluQuadricCallback(GLUquadric *qobj,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());

Comment: I would be suspect of the pre-processor definition of `CALLBACK`. It's usually defined in a system header to define the default calling convention for callbacks, but if it is defined incorrectly this sort of thing happens. `windef.h` usually defines it is `__stdcall`.

Comment: including windef.h helps. please see edit.

Comment: So, now you miss the required library(s). And show the exact error messages (or some part, if they all look similar).

Comment: yes, undefined reference to `glfwInit'. the tutorial uses cmake and it has a lot of makefiles. one is for mingw that has a LIB       = ../lib/win32/libglfw.a and a SOLIB     = ../lib/win32/libglfwdll.a but i can not find any .dll or .a files.

Comment: i made some progress, see edit2 above.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean [Tutorial 1: Opening a Window](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/) and are using Netbeans' builtin build system instead of CMake.

The order in which you include the header files is important ([source](http://www.glfw.org/faq.html#215__can_i_use_glew_with_glfw)). Try it like this:

```
#include <windef.h> // According to comments above
#include <GL/glew.h> // Before any gl headers
#include <GL/gl.h>

//#include <GL/glext.h> // Linux headers
//#include <GL/wglext.h> // Windows headers - Not sure which ones cygwin needs. Just try it

#include <GL/glu.h> // Always after gl.h
#include <GL/glfw.h> // When all gl-headers have been included
```

Create a directory named "include" in your project directory with a subfolder "GL".

Grab the binaries (32 bit, MinGW) from the [GLFW Download Site](http://www.glfw.org/download.html) and put the .dll/.so into your build-folder (Or extract them somewhere and add them to the search directories) and the header files into "include/GL".

Also the glfw code in the tutorial is slightly outdated; It does not work with glfw3 anymore.
You'll have to update it using GLFW's [conversion guide](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/moving.html)/try [this version](http://pastebin.com/fG711uMv) (which I haven't been able to test, since I'm currently not at home) or use glfw2.

Finally download the [GLEW sources](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and build it by following the instructions in the README.txt. Put the .dll/.so into your build-folder (or add to search directories) and the header files into "include/GL".

Add following to your Compiler-Flags:

```
-Iinclude/
```

Finally add following arguments to your Linker:

```
-L/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lGL -lGLU -lglfw -lglew
```

You should be able to compile the tutorial now.

Edit: Added instructions for building GLEW, GLFW and completed my answer to include building everything from scratch.
Edit2: Linked glfw3-version of the tutorial-code.
Edit3: Added missing linker options.

Comment: i did most of what you suggest, but i still get compile errors from things like GLFW_WINDOW’ was not declared in this scope, ‘glfwEnable’ was not declared in this scope, too few arguments to function ‘void glfwSwapBuffers(GLFWwindow*)’

Comment: This is most likely because you are trying to use glfw3 with the glfw2-api. **glfwEnable** is now **glfwSetInputMode**, **GLFW_WINDOW** was deprecated and is now removed, **glfwSwapBuffers** needs a pointer to the window you want to swap the buffers to. See [this creating a window guide for glfw3](http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) for the new way to create a glfw window. For a complete list of all changes I suggest looking into the [conversion guide](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/moving.html) I posted earlier.

Comment: I've linked to a modified version of the tutorial, which should work, in my answer.

Comment: the modified version compiles after a few conversion changes. i am now having problems getting netbeans to find the libraries.

Comment: having some luck using this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237915/setting-up-opengl-netbeans-project-with-glfw-on-ubuntu - now it finds the glfw3 and glew32 libraries. all need to do now is find and add the opengl library

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~wongam/d18_cygwin_opengl_setup/cygwin_opengl_setup.html). You also have to add **-L/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32** to the linker options when using cygwin. Forgot to add that to my answer, sorry.

Comment: i am using: -L/cygdrive/D/dev/glfw-3.0.3.bin.WIN64/lib-mingw -L/cygdrive/D/dev/glew-1.10.0/lib/Release/x64 -L../../../../../Windows/SysWOW64 -lglfw3 -lglew32 -lopengl32, but i still that unresolved extern and it's not happy with the 64 bit lib :(