# OpenGL programming with GLFW/GLEW

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, glew

I want to learn to use shaders and therefore created a new C++ project on Netbeans (ver. 8.0.2).

I want to include the GLFW and the GLEW Library like stated in this tutorial: http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Creating-a-window

I'm currently struggeling at importing glew properly. When using `#include <GL/glew.h>`, the compiler (I use GNU g++ on Windows10x64/Cygwin console) throws a huge list of errors. It seems to be a problem with `glu.h`. I removed the impot of glu.h inside of glew.h for testing purposes. This removed the errors, but also prevented openGL from loading completely (functions starting with gl were "undefined", like `glViewport`). So that cannot be the solution.

The output I get when calling the compiler on the normal glew.h:

```
g++ -m64   -c -g -Wall -I/cygdrive/C/Users/Erik/programming/Libraries/glew-1.13.0-win32/glew-1.13.0/include/ -I/cygdrive/C/Users/Erik/programming/Libraries/glfw-3.1.2.bin.WIN32/glfw-3.1.2.bin.WIN32/include/ -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/startup.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/startup.o startup.cc

In file included from /cygdrive/C/Users/Erik/programming/Libraries/glew-1.13.0-win32/glew-1.13.0/include/GL/glew.h:1202:0,
                 from startup.cc:5:
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 void APIENTRY gluQuadricCallback(GLUquadric *qobj,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
                                                                               ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected ')' before '*' token
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected initializer before '*' token
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:78:79: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 void APIENTRY gluTessCallback(GLUtesselator *tess,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
                                                                               ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:78:79: error: expected ')' before '*' token
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:78:79: error: expected initializer before '*' token
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:94:75: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 void APIENTRY gluNurbsCallback(GLUnurbs *nobj,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
                                                                           ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:94:75: error: expected ')' before '*' token
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:94:75: error: expected initializer before '*' token
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:96:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUquadricErrorProc)(GLenum);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:97:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessBeginProc)(GLenum);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:98:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessEdgeFlagProc) (GLboolean);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:99:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessVertexProc)(void *);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:100:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessEndProc)(void);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:101:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessErrorProc)(GLenum);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:102:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessCombineProc)(GLdouble[3],void*[4],GLfloat[4],void**);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:103:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessBeginDataProc)(GLenum,void *);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:104:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessEdgeFlagDataProc) (GLboolean,void *);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:105:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessVertexDataProc)(void *,void *);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:106:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessEndDataProc)(void *);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:107:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessErrorDataProc)(GLenum,void *);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:108:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessCombineDataProc)(GLdouble[3],void*[4],GLfloat[4],void**,void*);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:109:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUnurbsErrorProc)(GLenum);
                        ^
```

To me, (i'm no pro in C++ and thus not very good in interpreting error messages) it seems like `CALLBACK` is not defined yet. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: There is no language C/C++. Only the two **different** languages C and C++. Pick the one you actually use!

Comment: Don't just use links. A question is required to be self-contained. Learn [ask].

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of code that fails to compile ?

Comment: Are you sure you included all required headers? And can the compiler find them? Does `#include <GL/glew.h>` point to a valid, e.g. existing, file?

Comment: @Louen a minimalistic file (extension cc) like `#include <GL/glew.h>
int main() {
    return 0;
}` already fails

Comment: @ErikBrendel Let me guess, if you remove the `#include` everything works fine -> you have a problem with your include settings of you compiler :-)

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198244/how-do-i-get-rid-of-these-compiler-errors-in-glu-h might be what you look for :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it somehow (not beautiful, but at least somehow):

I tried importing `windef.h` like stated in the [link from @Louen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198244/how-do-i-get-rid-of-these-compiler-errors-in-glu-h).
This removed the CALLBACK-Error, but created a new one (something about APIENTRY). So I searched for the error-solving part of windef.h and found it:

```
#ifndef CALLBACK
#if defined(_ARM_)
#define CALLBACK
#else
#define CALLBACK __stdcall
#endif
#endif
```

Then i just pasted this in my file (instead of including whole windef.h).